# Live server in vs code not showing imges

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, liveserver

In vs code live server not showing the imges but when I open the html file in the chrome without the live server the imges are showing and everything is fine

Not : the html code is correct and the imges in the project file and everything is correct.

Please if you know the solution for this issue tell me

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask In order to help you, it's necessary to have more information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.